# Why do I get double colums when I append a dataframe without creating an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, append

```
txtfile=open('university_towns.txt','r')
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=('State','Region'))
state=''
for i in txtfile:
    if '[edit]' in i:
        i=i[:i.find('[')].strip()
        state=i
        continue
    region=i.strip()
    if '(' in region:
        k=region.find('(')
        region=region[:(k-1)]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[state, region]]), ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

In this code if I have already created an empty dataframe with column-names: `State` and `Region`. Now when I try to append the values `state` and `region`, obtained from parsing a text file, to dataframe, it's showing two extra columns named `State` and `Region` with `NaN` values. and another two columns named 0 and 1 with the actual values of state and region.

Now I changed the code like this:

```
#def get_list_of_university_towns():
txtfile=open('university_towns.txt','r')
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=('State','Region'))
state=''
for i in txtfile:
    if '[edit]' in i:
        i=i[:i.find('[')].strip()
        state=i
        continue
    region=i.strip()
    if '(' in region:
        k=region.find('(')
        region=region[:(k-1)]
df.loc[:,'State']=state
df.loc[:,'Region']=region
print(df)
```

Its showing empty data frame.The input is file copied from this Wikipedia page given in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_college_towns#College_towns_in_the_United_States

Comment: Hope my newly edditet answers helps you solve the issue

Comment: If the answer solved your Question, maybe set the answer as accepted. So others who search for a similar problem know what did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As an **Alternative Approach:**

you could also replace the complete append call this line of code:

```
df.loc[len(df), :] = [state, region]
```

This shoudl also work as it appends both variables you extracted as a list to the end of the dataframe.

---

**Cause of the Problem:**

The problem is, with your approach of creating a new dataframe on every iteration `df.append(pd.DataFrame())` is, that the newly created df lacks the column names of the original df

Could you try specify the column labels as this in your code? Like this:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([state, region], columns=('State','Region')),ignore_index=True)
```

---

You could also create lists called state and region and append all data to these list.
 After parsing the complete text file just create the dataframe with data you obtained from parsing the text file

```
df=pd.DataFrame([state,region], columns=('State','Region'))
```

Or assign the list to the columns by calling

```
df.loc[:,'State'] = state
df.loc[:,'Region'] = region
```

Comment: But then why do we have to create an empty dataframe with columns: State and Region in the first line. Doesn't that create a dataframe with columns state and region in the loop itself.??

Comment: df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[state, region]]), columns=('State','Region'),ignore_index=True)
Why there are two square brackets for [[state, region]]

Comment: #def get_list_of_university_towns():
txtfile=open('university_towns.txt','r')
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=('State','Region'))
state=''
for i in txtfile:
    if '[edit]' in i:
        i=i[:i.find('[')].strip()
        state=i
        continue
    region=i.strip()
    if '(' in region:
        k=region.find('(')
        region=region[:(k-1)]
    #df=df.append(pd.DataFrame([[state, region]],columns=['State', 'Region']),ignore_index=True)
    df.loc[:,'State']=state
    df.loc[:,'Region']=region
print(df)
When i tried this I am getting an empty dataframe

Comment: Removed two brackets. From the `df.append` can u try again? The empty dataframe has the right column labels and is empty. However the dataframe you create in the loop dont have column names. That is the reason why you find two Columns named 0 and 1 in the final file. Append tries to match the collumns of the new dataframe to tje existing. When there is now match new colums are created

Comment: Sorry wrote the code on my phone and hadnt a chance to test it. Could you provide a few lines of the text file as sample data. This would allow me to test. Just [edit] it to your original question (nore readable then in the comments) :)